# MySQL how to get count of rows for each keyword

Tags: mysql

i have a field in table1 called text. How can i count how many rows have the words "test", "test2" and "test3"?

so far i have:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE text LIKE "%test%" OR text LIKE "%test2%" OR text LIKE "%test3%"
```

but that only returns the entire count

i need something like:

```
test 100
test2 115
test3 12
```

can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a UNION will suit you well:

```
SELECT
    'test' AS `search_term`,
    COUNT(*) AS `term_count`
FROM table
WHERE text LIKE '%test%'
UNION
SELECT
    'test2' AS `search_term`,
    COUNT(*) AS `term_count`
FROM table
WHERE text LIKE '%test2%'
UNION
SELECT
    'test3' AS `search_term`,
    COUNT(*) AS `term_count`
FROM table
WHERE text LIKE '%test3%'
```